# Printing first half of a string in java

Tags: java

I am trying to take the first half of a string and only print the first half. For example, if the string is "Tomorrow", the print would be "Tomo"

I have seen people say to use `string.length() / 2`, but I tried this and it only prints the letter after the middle. In the example that would be "r". Just looking for a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you tried to print using `charAt` while you wanted to use `substring` :

```
System.out.println(yourString.substring(0, yourString.length() / 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
str.substring(0, str.length() / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain why your way prints 'r'.

The total length of word 'Tomorrow' is 8.

So half is 8/2 which is 4.

Now understand this,  `index` always start from zero. So the

> Zeroth letter is 'T'
>
> First 'o'
>
> Second 'm'
>
> Third 'o'
>
> Fourth 'r'

That is why it prints 'r'
To print first half of string you need to give starting and ending index which you can do by using `substring` method of `String` class

You can use like this :-

```
 str.substring(0, str.length() / 2);
```

Hope it makes crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
int len=yourString.length()/2;
String halfString=yourString.substring(0,len);
sysout(halfString);
```

Try above, just made it quite simple and modular for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Java's String class has a method called 'substring'

```
String s = "Tomorrow";
System.out.println(s.substring(0, 4));
```