# Remove first half of string using for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop

Variable `message` is the user inputed string. How do I make the substring run only to half.

```
public void deleteHalf(){

    
    String del = "";
    for ( int i=message.length(); i>=0; i++)
        del += message.substring(i,i-1);
    
    message = del;
    
}
```

Comment: I think if message is a string, this part is always true `i>=0;` Perhaps an implementation from this page can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618285/printing-first-half-of-a-string-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing first half of a string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618285/printing-first-half-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: ah, that's the problem but if I do i<=3; it does not look good.

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to use the `substring()` <sup>[1]</sup> method to get the second half of the `String` constant, you don't need to use a `for` loop:

```java
public class Test
{
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
         String text = "12345";
         System.out.println("Input: " + text + "\n" + "Output: " + deleteHalf(text));
     }

     public static String deleteHalf(String message)
     {
         return message.substring(message.length()/2);
     }
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
Input: 12345
Output: 345
```

---

<sup>1 - [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Even though your current logic says that you want to store the last part, I still want to know whether you want to delete the front half or the second half.
Based on that, you can use the following methods,

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
      String s = "result";
    System.out.println("result");
    System.out.println(deleteFirstHalf(s));
    System.out.println(deleteSecondHalf(s));
    
  
 }
 private static String deleteFirstHalf(String s){
     return s.substring(s.length()/2) ;
 }
 private static  String deleteSecondHalf(String s){
     return s.substring(0,s.length()/2) ;
 }}
```